# Inserting current_timestamp at time zone GMT gives local time instead

Tags: postgresql, sql-timestamp

I got a PostgreSQL database in which I have a date field in the invoices table:

```
Column           |           Type           |
payment_date     | timestamp with time zone |
```

The server is located at GMT-5, as you can see:

```
$date
Tue Jan 22 17:33:01 EST 2019
```

Getting the GMT time via a PostgreSQL command gives me:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT';
          timezone
----------------------------
 2019-01-22 22:33:01.087354
```

The problem is when I do an insertion/update:

```
update invoices set payment_date = current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT'
```

Then, when I get the query result...

```
select payment_date from invoices
```

it gives me:

```
2019-01-22 22:33:01.087354-05
```

**Wrong!** should be giving me *2019-01-22 22:33:01.087354-**00***

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field `payment_date` is of the (correct) type `timestamp with time zone`, so the `timestamp without time zone` that is the result of the `AT TIME ZONE` operation is converted using your session time zone.

PostgreSQL's `timestamp with time zone` data type does **not** store time zone information, it stores an UTC timestamp that is converted to the session time zone on display.

You are best advised to store the timestamp as `timestamp with time zone` and convert it to the desired time zone when you display it.